# Unable to load shared object on startup in RStudio only

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm not sure what I did, and my IS team is stumped. I updated R from 3.5.2 to 3.6.0 and R throws this error when opened in RStudio There is no problem when running R in the gui.

```r
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘stats’ in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I can navigate to the `stats.dll` file and the location matches my `.libPaths()`:

`"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.6.0/library"`

I have uninstalled and reinstalled both R and RStudio (1.2.1335). I have also restarted my computer. Any help or even temporary solutions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Since this is an RStudio specific problem, you might consider posting to their site: https://community.rstudio.com/

Comment: Thanks. I posted it there but haven't gotten much of a response.

Comment: As a way to narrow down the problem, try running RStudio as an administrator (right click to open it, *Run as Administrator* should be an option). If that works, my guess is that it is a permissions problem where RStudio doesn't have sufficient privileges to read from your `Program Files`.

Comment: That was a good suggestion but no dice :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on RStudio Community: I had a typo in one of the variables used in `Sys.getenv("PATH")`

https://community.rstudio.com/t/unable-to-load-shared-object-on-startup-in-rstudio-only/33107